# Preventing/Detecting forgery of logs generated in a potentially hostile environment

Tags: key-management, file-encryption

I have an application that runs on some host machine and generates logs. Later in the day those logs are securely transmitted to my machine.

The problem is that while the logs are being generated I dont have any access to the host machine whereas some users have full access to it and may want to forge the logs to their benefit. Is there a way to detect (or better yet prevent) such forgeries.

The log generating application may be modified to encrypt or insert MACs in the logs but encrypting/signing keys have to be on the same machine. Given that the malicious users may also have access to source code of the application, how do I go about protecting those keys?  Or are there other better techniques to tackle this scenario.

TIA

Comment: A running hash of the log by the application should be able to provide the integrity you need.  The user would have to inject log statements through legitimate functions in the application to keep the state of the hash correct.  Even using HMAC's with a hardcoded key, anyone modifying the logs outside the application wouldn't be able to keep the integrity of the hash at the end.  Are you assuming that a malicious user has modified the source code and re-run the logging application?

Comment: A running hash will prevent modification, but not truncation.

Comment: @raz i am assuming they wont be able to recompile because of some dependencies they wont be able to resolve (which is just a hope that they have better things to do in life :) ). So the problem reduces to securing a key in hostile environments when adversary has knowledge of key management scheme

Comment: @Mark have you heard of [`git rebase`](http://git-scm.com/book/Git-Branching-Rebasing)?

Answer (score 1):

If you run a service on a machine you don't trust, it will only generate results you cannot trust.

Even if you authenticate the logs somehow, they can change the log anyway, because they have access to the sourcecode. I assume you use some interpreted language (PHP, Python, Ruby) on the application.

One way to have secure logs is to send the entries offsite as soon as they are generated. Write the logs on a local file, but at the same time send them to your trusted server. A web service will be nice.

It won't prevent the malicious users to forge log entries and send it to you, but will make impossible to them to change the logs on your trusted server. If you send the logs using SSL, they cannot change the logs on-fly.

Later you can compare the consolidated received logs and the logs sent by the web service to see if they match.

Comment: I think the buck stops with your first sentence.  If we're assuming that they can recompile the application, then it doesn't matter what we do.  They can change the destination of the remove file for all we know, remove logging messages they don't want, or stop logging all together.

Comment: its compiled c++ in windows but cant assume there will be any connectivity while the logs are being generated

Comment: Honestly I think the first sentence says it all. If the machine isn't trusted it isn't trusted. Crypto is no fairy dust

Answer (score 1):

If you only store the logs on the machine, you can't prevent that logs got modified or deleted. And you cannot reliably detect it without at least one trusted element.

If you are only afraid from coworkers, you can use free dynamic web hosting services (just google for "free php mysql") as the trusted element, and make the workstation either send the whole log (encrypted if you want/have to) in realtime, or hashes of the log messages, to an application you coded. Make it in a way the application stores the time of each incident by itself, and only give the application on the workstation append-only access.

Comment: unfortunately i cant assume there will be connectivity while logs are being generated. Do you have any pointers on how to make a file append-only in windows ? Thanks